# Is there a way to add an "Edit HTML" button to bootstrap-wysihtml5 when integrating with Rails_Admin?

Tags: rails-admin, wysihtml5

The [Rails_Admin wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Text) explains how to integrate with bootstrap-wysihtml5 which is incredibly easy.

However, I'd like the wysihtml5 widget to have the "edit as html" button.

Is this possible?

Comment: I haven't. There's no config options anywhere (have you clicked on the link?) and all the documentation is javascript based. But this is integrated with rails_admin...? Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks likeitlikeit, but quite an important aspect of this question involves rails_admin integration... How do I edit these files in rails_admin

Comment: @andy Scratch my previous comment, sorry for that. The proper answer is below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure wysihtml5 on a per-field basis like below. To e.g. enable the HTML editor feature, use

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model Team do
    edit do
      field :description, :text do
        bootstrap_wysihtml5 true
        bootstrap_wysihtml5_config_options :html => true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This was added to Rails_admin [a while ago](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/commit/c9fcdb241fb98b4e0483d27d4876275cd044d248), but they somehow forgot to update the Wiki.

Comment: @andy Sorry, didn't really pay attention. This is of course also possible :) The correct answer is above.

Comment: Thanks, and you're welcome! Have fun with wysiHTML5, its an awesome project.

Answer (score 4):

The above answer is now out of date with the current version of Rails Admin. You should use the following syntax to customize the editor:

```
field :description, :wysihtml5 do
  config_options :html => true
end
```

I have updated the [wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Wysihtml5)